# Perl sort with time stamp using hash

Tags: perl, hashtable

I'm new to Perl and need help with sorting using the hash and/or any other possible method this can be done in Perl.

I've an input file like below and would like to generate the output file as shown.

I'm thinking if this can be done by putting it in hash and then comparing? Please also provide an explanations to the steps for the learning purpose if possible.

If the file has duplicate/triplicate entries matching with different timestamp, it should only list the latest time stamp entry.

Input file

```
A May 19 23:59:14 
B May 19 21:59:14
A May 22 07:59:14
C Apr 10 12:23:00
B May 11 10:23:34
```

The output should be

```
A May 22 07:59:14
B May 19 21:59:14
C Apr 10 12:23:00
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried the sort command but would like to see if this is possible with Perl hash as I've thousands of such entries and need something which can be done quicker. The sort command didn't though.

Comment: A hash won't help you to sort data. Please show the code that you tried

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use your data(A,B etc) as key and timestamp as value in perl hash. 
Then read input file and compare timestamps using perl time datatype. This way you keep only latest entries and other can be discarded. Print result at the end.

Comment: #! /usr/bin/perl  

%dls;  

open ( LOG, "/tmp/input_file" );  

while ( $line = <LOG> ) {  
#print $line;  
$dl = substr $line, 0,1;  
$timestamp = substr $line, 2;  
  if ( $timestamp > $dls{dl} ) {  
  $dls{dl} = $timestamp;  
  }  
}  

foreach $dlname (sort keys %dls) {  
          print TMP "$dlname,$dls{$dlname}\n";  
        }  

~

Comment: Sorry, I added two spaces on each line but still shows jumbled up..If you've suggetions on how to format , please do let em know

Comment: sorry for late comment. I see your code and at last what is `TMP` to which you are printing result.

Answer (score 1):

A hash is good for coalescing duplicates.
However sorting by *time stamp* requires converting the 'text' representation to an actual time. [`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.30/Piece.pm) is one of the better options for doing this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
my %things;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $letter, $M, $D, $T ) = split;
    my $timestamp =
        Time::Piece->strptime( "$M $D $T 2015", "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" );
    if ( not defined $things{$letter}
        or $things{$letter} < $timestamp )
    {
        $things{$letter} = $timestamp;
    }

}

foreach my $thing ( sort keys %things ) {
    print "$thing => ", $things{$thing}, "\n";
}

__DATA__
A May 19 23:59:14
B May 19 21:59:14
A May 22 07:59:14
C Apr 10 12:23:00
B May 11 10:23:34
```

Note though - your timestamps are ambiguous because they omit the year. You have to deal with this some way. I've gone for the easy road of just inserting 2015. That's not good practice - at the very least you should use some way of discovering 'current year' automatically - but bear in mind that at some points in the year, this will Just Break.

You can format output date using the `strftime` method within `Time::Piece` - this is merely the default output.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for guiding me and quick solution Sobrique. Thanks again for all your help.